# css animation-fill-mode foward changes element opacity

Tags: css, css-animations, opacity

Having an issue with an image when upon the image finishes its animation and is filled in forwards, it's opacity is lower than if i just load the image normally (with the animations taken out)

```
.header-container .col-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.header-container .col-2 img {
  opacity: 0;                       //
  animation: 0.5 header ease 1.25s; // these three lines seem to be the problem
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;    //
}

@keyframes header {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

I have looked at the styles on my browser (chrome) and can't work out why this is happening 
In the image is what the difference looks like + chrome styles

[img on right has slightly lower opacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUMkQ.jpg)

Thanks for any suggestions / help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>`animation: 0.5 header ease 1.25s;`</s>
the `0.5` without the time unit is interpreted as the [`animation-iteration-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) which, if set to `0.5` means: ***"Run my animation halfways."***

What you want is: `name, duration, easing, delay, fill-mode` use:

```
animation: header 0.5s ease 1.25s forwards;
```

and use the *`s`* or *`ms`* unit for the duration value.

Here's a reminder for the Animation shorthand order:

> name, duration, easing, delay, iteration-count, direction, fill-mode

```css
.header-container .col-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url("https://placehold.it/100x100/00f");
}
.header-container .col-2 img {
  opacity: 0;                       
  animation: header 0.5s ease 1.25s forwards; 
}

@keyframes header {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="col-2">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200/f00" alt="Test">
  </div>
</div>
```